# Can reading zipped files be faster than uncompressed?

Tags: compression

Is there any chance that packing a large file with some simple algorithm enables me to read the data faster than from an uncompressed file (due to the hard drive being slower than uncompressing)?
What kind of compression rate would I need to have? Can any fast compression algorithm do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  That is often the case with deflate compression, used by [zip](http://www.info-zip.org/), [gzip](http://www.gzip.org/), and [zlib](http://zlib.net/), when reading from hard drives with a typical compression factor of, say, four.

From SSDs, you may need to go to something with faster decompression.  One you could try is [lz4](https://code.google.com/p/lz4/).

Your mileage may vary.

Comment: Very interesting topic. I read a file in plain text (80MB), zip (27MB), gz (27MB), and bz2 format (17MB) with Python and get the following times:
.txt takes 0.043 sec,
.zip takes 0.30 sec,
.gz takes 0.42 sec, and
.bz takes 2.42 sec.
The times are about the same for HDD and SSD. When I double the file size, the times are about twice as long, so it's not bottlenecked by something else. I am so surprised that the plain text file, which is the largest, is by far the fastest to read. This appears to be limited by floating-point decompression time, not by transfer speed.

Comment: Python may not be the best way to do this test. (By the way, I am not aware of such a thing as "floating-point decompression".)

Comment: Good point.
(For the in-memory decompression, I merely meant it's CPU intensive.)

Comment: @NorbertS Thank you so much for this work. I was about to do exactly this analysis and you've saved me the trouble.

Answer (score 4):

You could also try [Density](https://github.com/centaurean/density.git), its command line client "sharc" is benchmarked [here](http://quixdb.github.io/squash/benchmarks/core-i3-2105.html#enwik8).